# Editable ListView items with Realm

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, realm

Every item in my list view is made up of `EditTexts` that the user can edit. The goal is, when the user focuses out of the specific edittext, the value he inserted will be saved in the `Realm` database.

Adding empty items to the list works great, but the actual saving of data is what I struggle with.

**What I did:**
In the adapter, I added an `onFocusChangeListener` to each of the edittexts. However, I can't seem to save the data for this specific row, or object.
I have the position of the item from the adapter, but I can't access a `RealmObject` by the position.

**My code:**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_exercise, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.etName = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etName);
        viewHolder.etWorkload = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etWorkload);
        viewHolder.etWeight = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.etWeight);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // assigning values
    Exercise e = adapterData.get(position);
    viewHolder.etName.setText(e.getName());
    viewHolder.etWorkload.setText(e.getWorkload());
    viewHolder.etWeight.setText(String.valueOf(e.getWeight()));

    // updating information
    viewHolder.etName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                Log.v(TAG, "saving ex. name: " + viewHolder.etName.getText());
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
                        // realm.where(Exercise.class).
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

   // ...
   // a listener for every edittext
```

Thanks.

Comment: You're having this much trouble because you're using `ListView` instead of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce How does having a RecyclerView solve my problems?

Comment: The biggest issue with ListView has always been handling focus in focusable items inside the list item.

Answer (score 1):

Just query by ID and make a final variable which you can access inside the anonymous class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter { // RealmRecyclerViewAdapter is better for htis
    // ...

    final Exercise e = adapterData.get(position);
    final long eId = e.getId();

    // updating information
    viewHolder.etName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                Log.v(TAG, "saving ex. name: " + viewHolder.etName.getText());
                realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        Exercise _e = realm.where(Exercise.class)
                                           .equalTo(ExerciseFields.ID, eId)
                                           .findFirst();
                        if(_e != null) {
                           // ...
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works, and it's great. However, it prevents me from having all the listeners in one function. With this solution, I have to repeat myself with roughly the same code for each of the fields. That is, for each of the fields, I have to add an onFocusChangeListener and update the database...